# Cannot SSH with IP address only via Bonjour

Tags: ssh, macos

I got a Pi zero W 2 on the same wifi network as my Macbook. I can login when I use the Pi's bonjour address:

```
ssh radio.local
```

but when I try via the IPv4 address it does not accept my password:

```
ping radio.local
PING radio.local (192.168.0.87): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.87: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=7.577 ms

ssh radio@192.168.0.87
radio@192.168.0.87's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

What am I doing wrong? I use the same password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh radio.local` is using the user name of the local host when trying to login on radio.local. What is `username` or `echo $USER`? Is it `radio`?

What does `ssh -v radio.local` say?

Is there anything relevant in your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: `echo $USER` this was the secret, I did not realize `radio` was not the username. When logging in with username it works, thanks!